# How to install Windows 7 on VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

I'm working using Ubuntu 14.0. I installed VirtualBox and  Windows 7 installed on it.

When I run Windows, the desktop is small and the rest is just grey. Changing screen resolution helped a bit, but still I can't maximise the window with Windows 7 (when I do it, the size of the part with Windows 7 reaches its maximum size and the border around it resizes).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like an Windows issue. I would ask on [su], where you can get help for Windows and Ubuntu at the same time.

Comment: It looks like the problem has nothing to do with installing Windows, but rather with configuring it after the instalation.

Comment: You will have better results after you had installed the [guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) to your Windows guest.

Comment: Did you try installing Guest Virtualbox addons? That usually fixes resolution errors, otherwise try installing the vm again.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try installing Guest Virtualbox addons.